# Pycharm 2017.3 and input function

Tags: python, pycharm

I am getting input value and save it in the variable. and the error message occurs as this. Here is my code:

```
    input_id = input("your id please")

    members = ['egoing', 'k8805']
    for member in members:
        if member == input_id:
            print("hellop"+member)
```

and here is the error message

```
/Python_Workspace/PycharmProjects/Practice/venv/bin/python /Python_Workspace/PycharmProjects/Practice/Container_Loop/4.py
your id pleaseegoing
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Python_Workspace/PycharmProjects/Practice/Container_Loop/4.py", line 1, in <module>
    input_id = input("your id please")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'egoing' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Many others asked similar questions and many answers highlighted raw_input and input function and its role after version change.
I just started python and currently using pycharm 2017.3 and didnot individually install python in my mac. Any advice why this error is happening?

Comment: Don't use `input` with Python 2; use `raw_input` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using Python 2, because the call to `input()` is trying to evaluate what you've entered, and that's why you're seeing that error message. It's looking for a variable with that name and not finding one.  You can change your call to `raw_input()` instead, which does not try to evaluate your input. 
 This will solve your problem.

In the future, if you want to see what version of python you're running, just type `python` inside a Terminal shell, and it will pop up some info at the top. For instance, when I run Py2 on my Mac, I see:

```
g$ python
Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 12:01:12) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

so I know I'm running Py 2.7.

Also, there is a change between Py2 and Py3. In Py2, there is both `raw_input()` and `input()`. Both read in a string, but `input()` evaluates the string, expecting the string to be the name of some global item, like a function or variable.
In Py3, things changed, and Py3's `input()` works just Py2's `raw_input()`. So, because your call to `input()` was trying to evaluate the entered string, I could tell you were running Py2.